# Exponential equations

Tags: exponential-function

Let $a,b\geq 1$ be integers and $k=\frac{a}{b}>1$. Solve $$(n+1)^k=n^k+1,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
It is clear that $n=0$ is a solution for such equation. I found that if $a,b$ are odd, then $n=-1$ is also a solution of the equation. Do you have another solutions?

Comment: Hint: $(n+1)^k-n^k$ strictly increasing

Comment: It has only 2 solutions, right?

Comment: Yes. $(n+1)^k-n^k$ strictly increasing for $n>0$. For $n<0$ it depends on $k$, but if $n+1<0$, function is monotone. So, you should check $n=0$ and $n=-1$; you checked it.

Comment: Even if n negative?

Comment: @Moti if $n$ is nagative, then $n=-1$ is only one solution for the equation (when $a,b$ are odd). Do you have another solution?

Comment: I need to think if $$n^{(k-1)}+n^{(k-2)}+...+1=0$$ has more than one solution for some k